# ReentrantReadWriteLock and synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

If I have a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, and I use it as the lock in a synchronized block, can other threads still release their locks?

For example:

```
ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);

public void doSomething() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        // do stuff
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

If I call `doSomething()` and another thread is already holding the read lock, can that thread release the read lock?

When I make the `doSomething()` call, I'll synchronize on the `ReentrantReadWriteLock` and then attempt to get the read lock. Since something is already holding the read lock, I will block until that lock is released. I am curious to know if the read lock *can* be released since I've synchronized on the lock itself.

Comment: Uuuh, why synchronize since you use a lock to begin with?? Also, you should lock in front of a `try` block and unlock in a `finally` block

Comment: It's existing code. I'm trying to figure out the source of a deadlock. I originally thought it was a dining philosophers problem but there's three threads involved. If it was up to me I wouldn't even include the read/write lock in the first place.

Comment: Im not sure what your exact question is. But `lock.readLock()` can be aquired by multiple threads. About this code ...i think is "oversynchronized" (if that word evenn exist :)) and in my opinion used wrongly. When you delete synchronized block code will to the same thing

Comment: There's write locks involved too. But I thought it would be simpler to only have one lock type in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing on a ReentrantReadWriteLock object seems like an incredibly bad idea.  Your example is locking two completely independent locks.  First, it locks the mutex that is built in to every object (in this case, the ReentrantReadWriteLock object), and then it locks the read lock.

Any time you see a lock, you should ask this question, "What is the invariant that the lock is supposed to protect?"  That is another way of asking, "In what way could your data be corrupted if the lock wasn't there?"

OK,  What does the `synchronized(lock)` protect?

And, What does the `lock.readLock().lock()` protect?

If both answers are the same, then why use two locks?

> If it was up to me I wouldn't even include the read/write lock in the first place

You might as well change your example to this:

```
Object lock = new Object();

public void doSomething() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        // do stuff
}
```

As far as the code you have shown us goes, it wouldn't behave any differently.  (Though, it might change how your example interacts with other code that you haven't shown us.)

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly trivial to write an example that shows one thread holding the monitor on the actual lock object does not obstruct other threads from acquiring and releasing the read lock.  (This is of course not actually documented so could in theory be different for an alternate Java implementation!)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);

    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        lock.readLock().lock();
                        try {
                            System.out.println("foo");
                        } finally {
                            lock.readLock().unlock();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("done");
        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```